# $\sup (1/A) = 1/\inf (A)$, for $\inf (A) > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Here is the textbook question:

$A$ is a nonempty set of positive real numbers.

Define $\frac{1}{A} = \{z = \frac{1}{x}\mid x \in A\}$.

Show that $$\sup (\frac{1}{A}) = \frac{1}{\inf (A)}$$

First forgive non math syntax, the question is posted from mobile

now,
if $\inf(A) > 1$
it is pretty straight forward

since for every $x \in A$ 
$\inf (A) \le x$
by simple operations
$z = \frac{1}{x} \ge \sup(A)$

but if $\inf(A)$ belong to $]0, 1[$ it is not possible

note that is the answer supplied by the textbook

Comment: Could you more clearly explain your reasoning for when $\operatorname{inf}(A)>1$? I don't see why it fails for smaller infima - and it also only looks like half of the necessary work (i.e. it looks like you show that $1/\operatorname{inf}(A)$ is a upper bound, but not necessarily that it is the supremum)

Comment: sure, inf (x) <= x, then 1/x <= inf (x), if inf (x) < 1, then 1/inf (x) < 1/x, similar to 1/2 <= 3/4, but 2 is not less than 4/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use a straightforward argument. Recall for a moment that $\inf A$ is characterized by the following two properties:

1. $\inf A \le a$ for all $a \in A$, and
2. for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $b \in A$ with the property that $b < \inf A + \epsilon$.

Now let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $b \in A$ (which by hypothesis satisfies $b > 0$) satisfying $b < \inf A + \epsilon$. Since $\dfrac 1b \in \dfrac 1A$ you may take the reciprocal of each side to find
$$\frac{1}{\inf A + \epsilon} < \frac 1b \le \sup \frac 1A.$$ Now let $\epsilon \to 0^+$ to conclude
$$\frac 1{\inf A} \le \sup \frac 1A.$$

The other direction can be proved in a very similar manner.