# Prove that $\inf(A^{-1}) = \sup(A)^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

This is very similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369782/sup-1-a-1-inf-a-for-inf-a-0) question, whose answer I do not understand. I want to proved that for $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$:

$$
\inf(A^{-1}) = \sup(A)^{-1}
$$

where $A^{-1} = \{\frac{1}{a} \mid a \in A\}$ and it is given that $\sup(A) < 0$.

My first attempt was this:

Let $i := \inf(A^{-1})$, then we know:

$$
\begin{align}
&(1) \quad \forall a \in A: \frac{1}{a} \ge i \\
&(2) \quad \forall \epsilon > 0 \in \mathbb{R}: \exists a \in A: \frac{1}{a} < i + \epsilon
\end{align}
$$

from which it follows that:

$$
\begin{align}
&(1) \quad \forall a \in A: a \leq \frac{1}{i} \\
&(2) \quad \forall \epsilon > 0 \in \mathbb{R}: \exists a \in A: a > \frac{1}{i + \epsilon}
\end{align}
$$

Now if I could show that $\frac{1}{i + \epsilon} \geq \frac{1}{i} - \epsilon$ that would show that $\sup(A) = \frac{1}{i}$ and conclude the proof. But I don't know how to show that that's true.

My second attempt was this:

Choose an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, then pick an $a \in A$ such that $a > \sup(A) - \epsilon$. Then we have:

$$
\frac{1}{\sup(A) - \epsilon} > \frac{1}{a} \geq \inf(A^{-1})
$$

and if we let $\epsilon$ go to zero we get:

$$
\frac{1}{\sup(A)} \geq \inf(A^{-1})
$$

but I don't know how to show that it also holds that:

$$
\frac{1}{\sup(A)} \leq \inf(A^{-1})
$$

because if repeat the procedure, picking an  $a$, such that $\frac{1}{a} < \inf(A^{-1}) + \epsilon$ then I also get:

$$
\frac{1}{\inf(A^{-1}) + \epsilon} < a \leq \sup{A}
$$

i.e.

$$
\frac{1}{\sup(A)} \geq \inf{A^{-1}}
$$

again.

How can fix one or both of these approaches? And where do I actually need to use $\sup(A) < 0$? Is the equality not true for $\sup(A) > 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple approach.

We know that for any $a$ in A, $$ a \leq Sup(A)$$
Or
$$\frac{1}{Sup(A)} \leq \frac{1}{a}$$

So $Sup(A)^{-1}$ is a lower bound to $A^{-1}$.
Since $Inf(A^{-1})$ is greatest lower bound to $A^{-1}$ we must have $Sup(A)^{-1} \leq Inf(A^{-1})$.

Now similarly $\frac{1}{Inf(A^{-1})}$ is an upper bound to the set $A$, $Sup(A)^{-1} \geq Inf(A^{-1})$. So we have your equality.