# Mininorm of Linear Isomorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamical-systems

Imagine $E$ is a finite norm space and $A:E \to E$ is a linear isomorphism, the mininorm of $A$ is defined as the following:
\begin{align}
m(A)=inf\{ |Av| , v\in E , |v|=1\}
\end{align}
|.| is the operator norm here. and $A$ is a bounded linear operator.

I want to prove $m(A) = |A^{-1}|^{-1}$.

Here is what I tried:

We know that the operator norm for bounded linear isomorphisms is defined; and :
\begin{align}
|A|=sup\{|Av|: |v|\leq 1\}
\end{align}
Moreover we know $\forall v \in E$ we have $|Av| \leq |A||v|$

so $|A^{-1}|=sup\{|A^{-1}v|:v\in E , |v|\leq1 \}=\frac{1}{inf{|A^{-1}v|}}=(m(A))^{-1}$, so
\begin{align}
m(A)=|A^{-1}|^{-1}
\end{align}

Is there anything wrong with my proof?

Comment: How to get from $\sup\{..\} = \inf\{ 1/\|A^{-1}v\|\}$ to $=\frac1{\inf \|A^{-1}v\|}$ ?

Comment: @daw I used this
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369782/sup-1-a-1-inf-a-for-inf-a-0

Comment: yes, but in the wrong (or non-obvious way)